# Is there a word for "explaining away the problems of a piece of art because you like the artist"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, questions, phrase-requests

Is there a word for the phenomenon of explaining away the problems with a piece of art because you like the artist, aesthetic, or something else other than the actual quality?

I'm as guilty of this as anyone. A perfect example is Star Wars. I love Star Wars (although not George Lucas particularly). Whenever people make fun of Han Solo saying "I made the Kessel Run in less than 12 parsecs" because parsecs are a unit of time, not distance, I explain this away by claiming that Han didn't regard the people he was talking to highly so he was being a dickish rogue to them when he assumed they didn't know what a parsec was. Another example is Metal Gear. The storyline in that is retarded, but I really really like the gameplay. So I'll try to explain away it's silliness by delving into wikipedia and coming up with explanations for every retarded plot hole and deus ex machina.

"Explaining away" isn't quite a descriptive enough phrase to describe this phenomenon. Is there a word for this? I feel like there's gotta be a French or German word for this. If there's not, let us please start referring to this as "French-wording a piece of art" (ie "stop french-wording Star Wars bro") or just call it "austining" cause that's my name.

Comment: We all know you meant that *parsecs are a unit of distance, not time*, but we'll explain this away. :) The word you are looking for is *spinning*, as in what politicians' press officers do.

Comment: Correction to my comment above: Is there a word for justifying what one likes in a science fiction movie when critics have found flaws (in the characters, story lines, etc.) in it?

Comment: @Lambie You say "Star Wars isn't a piece of art". OMG! How could you be so heartless! :P

Comment: @NVZ Well, it's art, it's just not "a piece of art". And, fyi, I am a mean old virago. But still, here :).

Comment: I would say you are [*retconning*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/retcon) or maybe *fan(boy) retconning*.

Comment: @1006a *retconning* is specific to the purpose of continuing a plot. OP describes a situation where someone has *rose-tinted glasses*. It might be in the context of continuing a plot, but might also be outside of that scope.

Comment: @bvpx the OP is describing actively coming up with explanations for errors, inconsistencies, and plot holes. Retconning is in extended use for all of these kinds of patch-ups, more often on the part of writers but also for fans who want to justify and perfect their favorite work of fiction.

Answer (score 4):

When you do that, you ***gloss over*** the problems.

TFD(idioms):

> **[gloss over](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/gloss+over)**
>   Make attractive or acceptable by deception or superficial treatment.
>
> For example, His resumé glossed over his lack
>   of experience, or She tried to gloss over the mistake by insisting it
>   would make no difference.
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer.
>   Copyright © 2003, 1997 by The Christine Ammer 1992 Trust. Published by
>   Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.

ODO:

> **[gloss](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gloss)**
>   *VERB*
>
> **2** [**gloss over**] Try to conceal or disguise (something unfavourable) by treating it briefly or representing it misleadingly
>
> ‘But though Einhard declared he would record nothing through hearsay,
>   he also glossed over facts unfavourable to his hero.’

Answer (score 2):

One possible verb option for this situation is **extenuate**. Here is the discussion of that verb in *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1984):

> "**Extenuate** ... implies the aim to lessen (as by excuses or explanations) the seriousness or magnitude of some crime, offense, or guilt [examples omitted] But the term is often used in the sense of make to excuses for [examples omitted]

That dictionary notes several other verbs with similar meanings, including **gloss over** (discussed in alwayslearning's answer), **palliate**:

> **Palliate** may may stress the concealing or cloaking or the condoning of the enormity of a crime or offense

and **whitewash**:

> **Whitewash**, and less often **whiten**, imply an attempt to cover up (as a crime, a defect or fault, or a person's guilt) by some such means as a superficial investigation, or a perfunctory trial, or a special report that leads to a seeming acquittal or exoneration or that gives the person or persons accused an appearance of innocence or blamelessness

*Palliate* seems too strong for the situation you ask about, but *whitewash* seems arguably applicable, and *extenuate* seems very much on point (as does *gloss over*).

Answer (score 1):

> "Explaining away" isn't quite a descriptive enough phrase to describe this phenomenon. Is there a word for this?

*Fanboying* is a word that could be used in place of "explaining away".

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fanboy

Edit: It seems as though *fanboying* is a informal word and is mostly listed as **informal** in dictionaries or found in various slang dictionaries online.

If you're doing any formal work it's best to use another word.

Comment: @bvpx - yes, please explain!

Comment: The linked Oxford definition of _fanboy_ **does not** support the assertions made in this answer, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

This is **confirmation bias**,"... a tendency of people to favor information that confirms their beliefs or hypotheses. People display this bias when they gather or remember information selectively, or when they interpret it in a biased way."

[thefreedictionary: confirmation bias](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Confirmation+bias)

Answer (score 1):

*You are **rationalising** the poor plot because you like the artist.*

or

*You are **making excuses for** the poor plot because you like the artist.*

> In psychology and logic, **rationalization** or rationalisation (also known as **making excuses**) is a defense mechanism in which controversial behaviors or feelings are justified and explained in a seemingly rational or logical manner to avoid the true explanation, and are made consciously tolerable—or even admirable and superior—by plausible means. It is also an informal fallacy of reasoning.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalization_(psychology))